# iOS metal resources - where to find

Tags: ios, metal

I'm currently coding up a large iOS 8 app using [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Its proven very frustrating due to the lack of non- trivial examples, and the fact is works (by design) a little differently than DirectX and OpenGL ES (both of which I know).

Currently, I can only find tutorials that use a single vertex/index buffer and then do fancy stuff in the shader.  I'd like to see how to manage having multiple objects with different vertices and shader uniforms drawn the same frame.

Comment: If Metal is still causing you trouble, you could have a look at [MetalGL](https://metalgl.com), which is an implementation of the OpenGL ES API in Metal. It provides many of the performance benefits of Metal, while allowing you to continue using the familiar OpenGL API. Using the OpenGL API also helps retain platform portability for your app.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MetalDeferredLighting/Introduction/Intro.html) is a good sample from apple which shows how to manage different objects and multiple shaders. It is just a project but there is also a [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-605/) where apple engineers explain how this project work.

Answer (score 0):

Try a useful metal library for iOS image and video processing called "MetalImage"
refer to github :https://github.com/erickingxu/MetalImage.git

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/danielrosero/ios-touchingMetal) you will find an implementation I did, getting documentation from different sources.

I think is a good starting point.

Basically you will find in this Swift project:

- 3D Model loading, texturizing and rendering.
- Shaders: vertex, fragment and kernel. In the kernel I implemented Loki for Random generation of colors.

Answer (score -1):

To modify the [RayWenderlich introductory metal tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/77488/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-getting-started) to draw multiple objects with different resources into the same frame you would first  need to make a separate MTLRenderPipelineState (defining the shaders among other things) and MTLBuffer (defining the vertices/indices) for each object.

Then, you can just loop through the objects in the Render Command Encoder and bind the unique objects and call drawPrimitives() prior to calling endEncoding()

-In step 4 of the "Rendering the Triangle" portion this:

```
let renderEncoderOpt = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
if let renderEncoder = renderEncoderOpt {
  renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
  renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
  renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 3, instanceCount: 1)
  renderEncoder.endEncoding()
}
```

Turns into this:

```
let renderEncoderOpt = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
    if let renderEncoder = renderEncoderOpt {
      for drawable in drawables {
        renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(drawable.pipelineState)
        renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(drawable.vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
        renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: drawable.vertexCount, instanceCount: 1)
      }
      renderEncoder.endEncoding()
```

Comment: I've already tried your example.  You cannot be assured the call to drawPrimitive will execute in the order you call them.  This is an issue when sending any uniform info to the shader (which I do).  AFAIK, you have to create a separate renderEncoder for each call to the pixel shader if you want to be assured of the correct execution.

Comment: Interesting . . .  I've never seen the order change.  Do you have a source / example for that?

Comment: Just add a setVertexBuffer or setFragmentBuffer call to your loop (with different params per object).  You'll see it.

Comment: DrawPrimitive will execute in the order you call them. What you have to keep in mind is that the data in your vertex buffers can not be changed until the GPU has finished with it (this may be as much as 2 frames later). If you go changing the data per-object, you'll see unpredictable behaviour that may appear as though the render order is changing, but it is not. You need to understand how the CPU and GPU work in parallel to fully understand Metal.